# set file colors on c++

Tags: c++, file, colors

I am drawing a chart in a text file and I want to set the rows color grey and white one by one but I couldn't find the function that can help me.
my compiler is code blocks on windows.
can anyone please tell me the number of these colors and related function?
thanks

Comment: There is nothing in the standard to do this in C++. You will need to ask about a particular environment in which you want to do this and you will probably get suggestions of libraries that can help you do this [ncurses in linux] or implementation details on how to do it manually [escape codes for the terminal]. If you don't add more information to the question it will probably be closed soon.

Comment: You need to get a separate library for that purpose. One of the easiest I think is [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible in c++ to change color of texts in a file

Answer (score 0):

A text file is just text. It has just nothing but the letters and punctuation. It has no notation of color or whatever. So you can't do it in C++ or anything else.

For formatting and colors there are special files - HTML, RTF  and others. If you want to write such thing you must ask the question that way.